# JPA flushing to Database before @PreUpdate is called

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am trying to capture the entity data in the database before the save is executed, for the purpose of creating a shadow copy.

I have implemented the following `EntityListener` in my Spring application:

```java
    public class CmsListener {
        
        public CmsListener() {
        }
        
        
        
        @PreUpdate
        private void createShadow(CmsModel entity) {
            EntityManager em = BeanUtility.getBean(EntityManager.class);
    
            CmsModel p = em.find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId());
            
            System.out.println(entity);
    
        }
        
    }
```

The `entity` does indeed contain the entity object that is to be saved, and then I inject the `EntityManager` using another tool, which works fine - but for some reason, the entity has already been saved to the database. The output of `CmsModel p = em.find(...)` results in identical data which is in `entity`.

Why is JPA/hibernate persisting the changes before @PreUpdate is called? How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is because em.find doesn't actually query the database but fetches the object from cache, so it actually fetches the same object entity refers to (with changes already applied).

You could check your database log for the query that fetches the data for entity.id to verify this is indeed the case or you could add a breakpoint in createShadow() and have a look at the database entry for entity at the time the function is called to see for yourself if the changes are already applied to the database at that time.

To actually solve your problem and get your shadow copy you could fetch the object directly from database via native query.
Here is an untested example of what this could look like:

```
public CmsModel fetchCmsModelDirectly(){
   Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT cm.id,cm.value_a,cm.value_b FROM CmsModel cm",   CmsModel.class);

   try{
      return q.getSingleResult();
   }catch(NoResultException e){
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if the entity is really updated to database? My suspect is that the change is only updated to the persistence context (cache). And when the entity is query back at the listener, the one from the cache is returned. So they are identical.

This is the default behavior of most of the ORM (JPA in this case) to speed up the data lookup. The ORM framework will take care of the synchronizing between the persistence context and the database. Usually when the transaction is committed.

Comment: The entity is -NOT- in the database, but when querying the ORM it shows that it is there.

Comment: So - I have a custom repo that does a refresh() on the entity, where it grabs the latest data from the database. When I call refresh, it reverts to its prior state. This is expected. What I did not expect, was that I created a new instance of the entity by querying the database, and called `refresh()` on that. In this case, both the cached save model and the new instance were reverted to the current state of the database. Is there a way to create an instance of the entity where it doesn't appear as a reference to the other?

Comment: That's not the way it works in terms of EntityManager/Persistence Context as far as I know. The entity is cached in the Persistence Layer/Context.
It doesn't matter where you lookup/create the entity from the application. The same instance from the persistence layer is returned. And it's not necessary that every time you lookup the entity, the Persistence Layer lookup the data from the database.